# Dynamic HTML via jQuery with Razor functionality

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, razor

Using jQuery, I am dynamically adding a group of `<ul>` elements to a `<div>` using `.append`. I loop through a table containing a value for each `<ul>` I want added. That part works fine. Where I am having an issue is trying to add Razor functionality to the `<li>` elements.

Although the end result HTML produced looks to be syntax correct HTML, the Razor code does not function.

End Result HTML:

```
<div id="div_1">
    <label>Clients</label>
    <ul>
        @if (Model.details != null)
        {
            foreach (var itm in Model.details.OrderBy(i => i.value))
        {
            <li>@itm.value</li>}
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

The HTML above is what is produced by my `.append` code. It can be hard coded into my `cshtml` page and works perfectly. Adding it via `.append` at run time does not which I assume revolves around creation time or sequence?

Scaled down version of my code below:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult ClientMap()
{
    var db = new EDM_Client();
    List<client_map> map = new List<client_map>();
    map = db.client_map.ToList();

    return Json(map, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

csHTML:

```
<div id="divDetails" class="row">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
//getClientMap temporarily called from a button click
getClientMap(function (map) {
    $.each(map, function (idx, obj) {
        $('#divDetails').append('<div id="div_' + obj.detail_id + '">' +
                                    '<label>' + obj.detail_hdr + '</label>' +
                                    '<ul>' +
                                        '@if (Model.details != null)' +
                                        '{' +
                                            'foreach (var itm in Model.details.OrderBy(i => i.value))' +
                                            '{' +
                                                '<li>' +
                                                    '@itm.value' +
                                                '</li>' +
                                             '}' +
                                         '}' +
                                     '</ul>' +
                                 '</div>');           
    });
});

function getClientMap(output) {
$.ajax({
    url: './Client/ClientMap',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {            
        output(data);
    }
});
```

I am trying to do this dynamically so `<ul>` can be easily added/deleted via table entries rather than coding changes.

Any advice on how to make this work (or an alternative way) is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery runs on the client's machine, so when you use it to generate Razor code, the client machine cannot run that code because it has to run on the server.

You can put the Razor code directly where it should be, and then use jQuery to show/hide the options as required.

Alternatively, change your Ajax method `ClientMap` to return a partial view instead of JSON string, then use the jQuery's `html()` function to add the HTML returned from Ajax:

```
$('#divDetails').html(data);
```

Comment: Wow I suffered from the "can't see the forest for the trees" syndrome. So simple to do this standard Razor in cshtml. Thank you @Racil.